# unbuffered channel - multiple value passing

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    in := make(chan int, 10)
    out := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        in <- i
    }

    close(in)

    go func() {
        for {
            i, ok := <-in
            if !ok {
                close(out)
                break
            }

            out <- i * 2 //THIS LINE
        }
    }()

    for v := range out { // AND HERE
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

I am a bit new to Go and learned the difference between buffered and unbuffered channels, but I am not sure how this code works. Since the `out` channel is not buffered should not it create deadlock? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` channel is unbuffered so if you write to it without another goroutine waiting to read from it, it will block. Same for read: it will block until another goroutine writes to it. So, the goroutine blocks on write to out until the for loop in main reads from it. The main goroutine will read from out until it is closed, so when the  goroutine finally closes out, the for loop terminates.

Comment: So, the `for` loop "does not take the snapshot of the channel and it's ***length***" and loop through? Is it correct to say that "range" is dynamic on runtime, till the channel obsolete?

Comment: Range over channel will read from that channel until channel is closed. It will block until somebody writes to it.

Comment: yes it is. In the goroutine, when in is closed, it also closes out.

Answer (score 1):

Following how it is working:

> in := make(chan int, 10)
> out := make(chan int)

Above you are creating two channels. `in` is buffered can hold 10 values. `out` is unbuffered can hold only 1 value

> for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
> in <- i
> }

Above you are adding 10 values [0-9] to your in channel

> close(in)

Above you are closing write on `in` channel. Keep in mind read on `in` is still open.

> go func() {

You are creating a go routine to read values of `in` channel. (Best practice really is to pass the `in` to the func but that's not of focus here.

> ```
>    for {
>        i, ok := <-in
> ```

Above in your loop you read value till `in` is empty (`ok` will be false when it's empty)

> ```
>        if !ok {
>            close(out)
>            break
>        }
> ```

Above you would close `out` and break when you are done reading values from `in`. Till then below line executes.

> ```
>        out <- i * 2 //THIS LINE
> ```

Above you write to channel `out` and block this goroutine till it's value is read. The cycle would continue 10 times.

> for v := range out { // AND HERE
> fmt.Println(v)
> }

Above, back in main goroutine, you would read value from `out`, block and pass control to the other goroutine. This continues till for loop breaks and `out` is closed.